# How to use Apollo graphQL to merge results?

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I'm trying to follow the instructions in [Apollo graphQL pagination](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api/) to fetch results and then fetch the next page and merge them. Inspecting the cache I can see that it is updated with the new results, but the results on my page do not update and only show the first page. What am I doing wrong?

index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
        typePolicies: {
            Query: {
                merge: true,
            },
        },
    },
)

const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/graphql',
    cache: cache,
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App/>
    </ApolloProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

app.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Characters from "./characters/characters";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Characters/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

characters.tsx:

```
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import CharactersView from "./charactersView";

const query = gql`
    query Characters($page: Int) {
      characters(page: $page) {
        info {
          count, pages, next, prev
        }
        results {
          id, name, image
        }
      }
    }
    `

export default function Characters() {
    const { loading, error, data, fetchMore } = useQuery(query, {
        variables: {
            page: 1,
        },
    })

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

    return (
        <CharactersView
            characters={data.characters.results || []}
            next={() => fetchMore({
                    variables: {
                        page: data.characters.info.next,
                    },
                },
            )}
        />
    )
}
```

charactersView.tsx:

```
import CharacterModel from "./characterModel";

interface Props {
    characters: CharacterModel[]
    next: () => void
}

export default function CharactersView({ characters, next }: Props) {
    const chars = characters.map((character: CharacterModel) => (
        <div key={character.id}>
            <p>
                <img src={character.image} alt={character.name}/>
            </p>
            <p>
                {character.name}
            </p>
        </div>
    ));

    return (
        <div>{chars}
            <p>
                <button onClick={next}>Next</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}
```